# How do I pull after a rebase?

Tags: git

I have two local repositories. I created a topic branch on the first and then cloned it to a second repository. Then I ran "rebase -i" on the topic branch on the first and changed the first two commits on the topic branch. I switched to the second repository and ran "git pull" and it says that all changes are up to date. Running "git log" I can see that it is not up to date, as the SHA tags differ. How can I get git to pull the changes over again in the second repository?

Comment: Have you checked out the topic branch on the second repo?

Comment: Yes I checked it out and then ran git pull

Comment: Paste the output of `git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate` (both repos) and `git pull` (second repo) into the question.

Answer (score 1):

You should do this in your local branch

```
get fetch remote_name your_branch
git reset --hard remote_name/your_branch
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I hadn't yet finished rebasing changes in the first repo so the log looked different but it became clean when running "git branch".